# Updated angular project to version 12 from 9. After that module using Plotly.js is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, plotly, angular12

this is my app module file
all bits and pieces are at the same place as mentioned in document

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import * as PlotlyJS from 'plotly.js-dist';
import { PlotlyModule } from 'angular-plotly.js';

PlotlyModule.plotlyjs = PlotlyJS;

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    PlotlyModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

below is the error i am getting in cosole

```
main.ts:12 Error: Invalid PlotlyJS object. Please check https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js#quick-start to see how to add PlotlyJS to your project.
    at new PlotlyModule (angular-plotly.js.js:520)
    at Object.PlotlyModule_Factory [as factory] (angular-plotly.js.js:529)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11416)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11236)
    at core.js:11273
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at R3Injector._resolveInjectorDefTypes (core.js:11273)
    at new NgModuleRef$1 (core.js:25336)
    at NgModuleFactory$1.create (core.js:25390)
    at core.js:29276
```

Comment: Did you also update the plotly libraries to their latest versions?

Comment: Yes i did update

Answer (score 1):

I checked the documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-plotly.js?activeTab=readme. Looks like the import varies for PlotlyJS:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import * as PlotlyJS from 'plotly.js/dist/plotly.js'; // this line
import { PlotlyModule } from 'angular-plotly.js';

PlotlyModule.plotlyjs = PlotlyJS;

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, PlotlyModule],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I tried this too but its also giving same error

Answer (score 0):

```
$ npm install angular-plotly.js plotly.js-dist-min --save

$ npm install @types/plotly.js-dist-min --save-dev

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import * as PlotlyJS from 'plotly.js-dist-min';
import { PlotlyModule } from 'angular-plotly.js';

PlotlyModule.plotlyjs = PlotlyJS;

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, PlotlyModule],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Add following piece to angular.json. This should resolve the issue.**

```
{
    "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
            "scripts": [
                "node_modules/plotly.js-dist-min/plotly.min.js"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain a little more about how this line could fix the issue, it didn't work for me